# Invoking a function from another class with Boost in c++

Tags: c++, boost

I am fairly new to both c++ and the boost library.

What I want to do is invoke a method `foo` from a class `Bar` inside a class `Baz`. Here is basically what I want to achieve:

```
Baz::doSomething() {
    Bar bar;

    boost::thread qux(bar.foo);
}
```

And the `foo` function could be something like:

```
// bar.cpp

void foo() {
    const int leet = 1337; // Very useful
}
```

However, when I try to compile it tells me that:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:215:9: note: candidates are: boost::thread::thread(boost::detail::thread_move_t<boost::thread>)
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:201:18: note:                 boost::thread::thread(F, typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_convertible<T&, boost::detail::thread_move_t<T> >, boost::thread::dummy*>::type) [with F = void (Snake::*)(), typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_convertible<T&, boost::detail::thread_move_t<T> >, boost::thread::dummy*>::type = boost::thread::dummy*]
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:154:9: note:                 boost::thread::thread()
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:122:18: note:                 boost::thread::thread(boost::detail::thread_data_ptr)
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:113:9: note:                 boost::thread::thread(boost::thread&)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Beware that when `bar` goes out of scope at the end of `Baz::doSomething`, it's going to be destructed - regardless of what the new thread is doing.  This could happen before the thread even has a chance to start.

Comment: Either hold on to it as a member of `Baz`, or allocate it on the stack, or create it somewhere else.  Holding it on the stack and passing it to a new thread is trouble, unless you explicitly wait for the thread to finish before returning from `doSomething`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boost::thread qux(boost::bind(
    &Bar::foo,      // the method to invoke
    &bar            // the instance of the class
    ));
```

Answer (score 3):

Member functions are different from free functions.
You need to use [std::mem_fun_ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/mem_fun_ref/) to get a functor and [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html) (or `std::bind` should your compiler support it) to bind the object on which the function should be called on to use them.

The end result should look something like this:

```
boost::thread qux(boost::bind(&Foo::bar, bar)); // makes a copy of bar
boost::thread qux(boost::bind(&Foo::bar, &bar)); // make no copy of bar and calls the original instance
```

Or don't use `bind` and let `thread` do the binding:

```
boost::thread qux(&Foo::bar, &bar);
```

Edit:
I remembered wrong: You don't need `mem_fun`, `boost::bind` supports pointers to members out of the box.

Thanks for the comments addressing the issue.

Comment: `boost::bind` is not needed here -- `boost::thread`'s constructor [already does binding internally](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.multiple_argument_constructor). I.e., `boost::thread qux(&Foo::bar, bar);` works just fine.

Comment: You need to pass a pointer to the instance of the class containing the member.

Comment: @ravenspoint : Boost.Bind, and consequently Boost.Thread, ["*accept a pointer, a reference, or a smart pointer to an object as its first argument*"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers), so passing `bar` by value is perfectly valid.

Comment: @ildjarn But ravenspoint is right in so far, that my code is making a copy, which is certainly not intended by the OP. I remember why I was always using std::mem_fun in such situation, I simply find the automatisms in `bind` confusing.

Comment: @pmr : No, your code isn't making a copy; `thread` and `bind` [take all arguments by reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html#Limitations), not value. I.e., your code suffers from the object lifetime issues @Eclipse mentioned, but you're not copying any objects.

Comment: I was referring to the second argument.  As pmr points out, if you don't pass a pointer you get a copy

Comment: @ravenspoint : I knew which argument you were referring to, but no -- the *docs* point out that if you pass by value you *don't* make a copy.

Comment: @ildjarn http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers says "internal copy of x"

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was hung up on the fact that it gets _passed_ by reference, and didn't consider further how it was stored. Apologies to you and @ravenspoint :-]